# Authentication Token Grant Access to rest services mobile

Tags: html, web-services, rest, mobile

Folks, I am building a mobile application  on a subscription base model. So I want to be able to see which users have active accounts with my app and be able to turn off the rest services that they will call on their mobile application, what is the best way to achieve this? My rest services will be built on AWS and the mobile application for my customers will be just a thin client using get/post request to AWS WebServices.

Do I have to model my database to see this from an admin perpective? is there an commercial app that already provide me this control, or should I code this myself on a login method to check if their account is active?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use an authentication layer to start with. A simple login, key cloak based single sign-on or anything that fits your need. Then you need to have a DB/persistence layer where you have modeled your user with the kind of subscription models you're offering and which APIs can be accessed by those subscription models. So a few relational tables + FK constraints should do your backend. Can be implemented as web services themselves this authentication AND authorization layer.

Comment: Thanks CodePhobia, I already created the database and will look into the persistence layer.